# jQuery: Load data on a combo box depending on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have two combo boxes.

Let's say the first one had values A, B, C

And when I select A the second one should show me options 1, 2, and 3

If I select B, then the second one should have the options 4, 5, and 6

and C should make the second combo box have the options 96, 98, 100.

Is there a way to do this via jQuery??
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ajaxray.com/blog/2007/11/08/jquery-controlled-dependent-or-cascading-select-list-2/

Comment: I have a question though, when the page first loads, the second combo box is empty, do you know how I can fix that?? If I change the values of the first box then it loads the second box's values, but when the page loads, the second is completely empty. Thanks

Comment: The post permalink has been changed. It's now at-  http://ajaxray.com/blog/jquery-controlled-dependent-or-cascading-select-list-2/